# Gradle build.gradle code style for specifying version number of the dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, coding-style

For the 3rd part or android dependencies added in the module level gradle file, what is the right way to specify version number.
I have seen following the pattern of defining version number as a variable and using that.
Is that the recommended one? Does it really make any difference?

```
def constraintlayoutVersion = '2.0.4'

implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintlayoutVersion"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is preferred when the same version code is used in the multiple dependencies like kotlin

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

but for single use, it is not preferred.